Is there a way to use leaflet with 1-axis only zooming?
What I'm trying to build is a history log for spectral waterfall data. So for example I have an image which is 800 width by 800 height. Where width is frequency range, say 0-800MHz, and 800 - is time range, each tick is 100ms, so its 80s.
Now what I want to do when I zoom in - not to enlarge both width and height by two, but ONLY width, e.g. frequency range, since I don't want time domain to change. So its sort of "spreading" by one axis, instead of zooming.
If say I have tiles 200*200px, and have only two zoom levels: 0 and 1, I would have this folder structure:
For zoom level 0:
images/0/0_0.png
images/0/0_1.png
images/0/0_2.png
images/0/0_3.png
...
images/0/3_0.png
images/0/3_1.png
images/0/3_2.png
images/0/3_3.png

For zoom level 1:
images/1/0_0.png
images/1/0_1.png
images/1/0_2.png
images/1/0_3.png
images/1/0_4.png
images/1/0_5.png
images/1/0_6.png
images/1/0_7.png
...

images/1/7_0.png
images/1/7_1.png
images/1/7_2.png
images/1/7_3.png
images/1/7_4.png
images/1/7_5.png
images/1/7_6.png
images/1/7_7.png

Can someone give me example or point to one where I can implement such "spreading" instead of zooming rendering 800*800 image container in a webpage with leaflet?
Thx
Tried chatgpt and googling, not helped.

https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds
